# In Symfony2 project how can I pass an array as value to submit method

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

In Symfony2 project how can I pass an array as value to submit method ?

My form need 7 parameters, so when I do it with a `handleRequest()` way it's work fine by filling the form manually, but if I try with an array and `submit()` it fails.

Note that the array I pass to the submit method is not in the same order, has no token and has 8 values instead of 7.

And of course I don't use the handleRequest method.

But the key of the $data[0] array are the same that the name of the entity's properties

```
$addForm = $this->createForm('ns_add', $entity);
$addForm->submit($data[0]);
```

**EDIT : Almost good, with :**

`$addForm = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, 'ns_add', $entity);`

All the parameters are passed to the form, I can see it on the Symfony profiler (the tool under every Symfony application), but I still have one error : The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

Since I have all 7 my field filled + 1 the submit field I only have the "_token" field missed, so I try to add it to my `$data[0]` but it don't appear on the var_dump of my array, but if I add a key other than "_token", it appear (and cause error : no extra field allowed or kind).

So I was thinking is because of the token of my first form. In fact the real form is a 7 inputs text form, but I created a export button that extract the configuration of the entity I export.

And then, when I upload the file via the form that contain the configuration, I already have the TOKEN. This is a view of the FORM SECTION on the profiler :

```
ns_zippedfile [ns_zippedfile]
    file [file]
    ok [submit]
    _token [hidden]
(no name) [ns_add]
    name [text]
    adapter [choice]
    dbname [text]
    host [text]
    port [text]
    username [text]
    password [password]
    submit [submit]
```

So maybe I need to find a way to not merge the forms, this no name section confuse me.

Comment: var_dump($data) please

Comment: @ArturVesker $data is just a array index of an associative array, so I use `$data[0]` to access it, now I try use te setters of the entity instance object to construct a whole complete object and pass it to the submit method but still don't work :/

Comment: Can you show ns_add form fields?

Comment: The fields are the same of the keys of the `data[0]` array, but not on the same order, and the is an extra key

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$addForm = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, 'ns_add', $entity);
```

instead of

```
$addForm = $this->createForm('ns_add', $entity);
```

Don't care about fields order.

You can disable CSRF protection if it don't need:

```
$addForm = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, 'ns_add', $entity, ['csrf_protection' => false]);
```

Comment: Where you take data for $data[0]? I update my answer about csrf

Comment: From data I retrieve via the content of an imported file via a form (the form you see on the edit of my question `ns_zippedfile [ns_zippedfile]
    file [file]
    ok [submit]
    _token [hidden]...`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem,

```
$addForm = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, 'ns_add', $entity);
```

was good, but instead of null parameter I better put the same value that the parameter 2, `ns_add` . Works fine.

```
$addForm = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createNamed('ns_add', 'ns_add', $entity);
```

N.B.: Don't forget to generate the token and save it in the array of data for the field :

`$data[0]['_token'] = $this
    ->get('form.csrf_provider')
    ->generateCsrfToken('ns_add')
;`

N.B.2:`ns_add`, here is the name of my form, view `getName()` method of your EntityType class form.